# How do I create a REST call in SharePoint 2013 Designer to delete records from the Workflow History List?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api, delete

I use the Workflow History List for debugging and the option of turning on debugging for flows that are in production.  I would however like a workflow that purges the records in this list based by the workflow Name.  I have created a workflow and a Delete HTTP request, but can't get it to work.  I can't find any documentation on how to do this.  What I have is

```
 [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow
```

History')?$select=Id as my String in my Call

I get the following response code:

## response=PreconditionFailed

I think I'm getting it, but still don't know how to put the pieces together.  My understanding now is that I create a HTTP Rest to select the IDs of each record.
Then I have to follow it with two more HTTP requests one to get the item and the other to delete the item.  It is these later two that I don't know how to do.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Request like below.

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow%20History')/item(1)
```

The following example shows how to delete a list item.

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items(item id)
method: POST
headers:
     Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
     X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    "IF-MATCH": etag or "*"
    "X-HTTP-Method":"DELETE"
```

You can refer to the article below to do a POST request using REST API in SharePoint designer.

[SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflows and POST REST API](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflows-and-post-rest-api/)

Comment: I understand that once I get the ID; then need to create a POST REST call, but though I am a seasoned programmer and I've written very sophisticated workflows in SharePoint, my experience with the REST operation is only GETS and I still have issues parsing multi-column attributes from custom lists.  Your example seems concise and simple, I have no clue how to implement.  I know I must create some dictionary fields and possible a single call statement, but that's it.  I have looked at your reference, and based on my knowledge base, it doesn't help me.  If you could spell it out more simply pls